# 2D array, Storing and calling

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I think I may be misunderstanding how to store my information into my array and then to call it for later use.
The following code is to ask a user for how many Cd's they have and allow them to enter the Genre, Artist, and Title. Then it is to go back into the loop if there is more than one cd. I believe that I have everything mostly correct but my output is not right. Whenever entering in for 2 Cd's I will be allowed to enter the first three items in for CD 1 but it will then print CD 2 and just go straight to the end of the program.

-I have posted the code along with what happens when entering 1 CD vs 2 CDs

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RiverCDs 
{

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
    int cdTotal = 0; // user controlled, controls the number of rows.
    int col = 3;    // constant that controls array col.
    String value = " "; // holds input for array.
    int intervals = 1;  

    String [][] list = new String [cdTotal][col];

    System.out.println("The River Catalog:\n");
    System.out.print("How many CD's do you have:  ");
    cdTotal = scnr.nextInt();

    do 
    {
        if (cdTotal <= 0)               // checking for bad data.
        {
            System.out.print("Must be a number greater than 0.\n");
            System.out.print("How many CD's do you have:  ");
            cdTotal = scnr.nextInt();
        }

    }while(cdTotal <= 0);               // set up to catch more bad data.

    System.out.print("\nFor each CD, enter the genre, then the artist, then the title.\n");

    for (int i = 1; i <= cdTotal; i++) // incrementing cd based on user input.
    {
        System.out.print("\nFor CD " + i + ":\n");

        while (intervals <= 3)// condition to exit while loop for next cd.
        {

            System.out.print("Enter:  "); // outside of for-loop to Enter three items.
            value = scnr.nextLine();
            scnr.next();                 // clearing buffer so as to to print a double Enter.

            for (int r = 0; r < list.length ; r++) // enters row according to how many cdTotal equals. 
            {   
                for (int c = 0; c < list[col].length; c++) // enters col in each row up to three.
                {
                    list[r][c] = value;// storing array in value for later use.
                }
            }

            intervals++;                // incrementing so as to break loop and print next cd statement.
        }
    }


    System.out.print("\nHere is your catalog:\n");
    System.out.printf("\n%-20s" + "%-20s" + "%-20s\n","Genre","Artist","Title");
    System.out.println();

    for (int r = 0; r < list.length; r++)// accessing list rows
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < list[r].length; c++)// accessing list col to pull out individual parts of data.
        {
            System.out.printf("%-20s","%-20s","%-20s",list[r][c],list[r][c],list[r][c]); // constant to check for data in array- 
                                                                                               //not working
            //System.out.printf("%-20s","%-20s","%-20s",list[1][0],list[1][1],list[1][2]);
        }
    }
    scnr.close(); // turning off scanner to allow no more input.
}
```

}

1CD-
The River Catalog:

How many CD's do you have:  1

For each CD, enter the genre, then the artist, then the title.

For CD 1:
Enter:  top
Enter:  cami
Enter:  havana

Here is your catalog:

Genre               Artist              Title

2CD-
The River Catalog:

How many CD's do you have:  2

For each CD, enter the genre, then the artist, then the title.

For CD 1:
Enter:  top
Enter:  cami
Enter:  havana

For CD 2:

Here is your catalog:

Genre               Artist              Title

Comment: Please ask what do you want exactly.

Comment: When asking how many CD's there a person may enter whatever number they like. The code should allow the user to enter in the Genre, Artist, then the Title. After the first iteration it should go on to the next CD. This is also where the code will stop and just print out my format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code is a problem:

```
        for (int r = 0; r < i ; r++) // enters row according to how many cdTotal equals. 
        {

            for (int c = 0; c <= col-1; c++) // enters col in each row up to three.
            {
                list[r][c] = value;  // storing array in value for later use.
            }
        }
```

This code sets *every* value in the array to `value`, if `i` is large.  And you aren't changing `value` inside the loop, so everything in your array will be exactly the same thing.

Comment: So instead of I should I be using my cdTotal ?

Comment: You're doing CD number `i` at any given time, right?  So it's `list[i][something]`.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. You are right I'm using I to control the cd iterations. So maybe I should change it to `list[I][c] =value;`